# Design editor is unavailable until a successful build - build failed

Tags: android, build.gradle

[image]

Hi all, what is the actual root cause of this issue? I already sync with gradle files but eventually failed.

Answer (score 1):

No Need to Downgrade, just paste this line in your `gradle.properties` and you're done

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use a version less than 4.6

Open the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and change the version number.

For example, try 4.4 [as per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.3.2, I could fix it by,

```
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Modules(Properties Tab) -> Change the compile Sdk Version and Build Tools Version to the the latest version available at the time -> clean the project -> rebuild the project -> done

[I was facing the same issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SMUD.png)

[I updated the Compile Sdk Version and Build Tools Version to 30(latest at the time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC05S.png)

[problem resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AILhz.png)